# Red Green and a Star

Tags: color, logo

This is a programmer looking for suggestions. I'm tasked with designing a logo in red and green accent colors, as well as incorporating a star shape in the design.
I've made sure to make it clear that I'm not a graphic designer, they still wanted to get something.

I don't like stars in general and knew it'd give me trouble. I've googled some star logos, and to no surprise they all look meh. As for the colors, I think green on red is a stupid choice especially for a medical company. This whole thing is giving me trouble and I'm out of ideas at what to come up with.
[image]

Anything I should be aware of concerning red and green colors?

Comment: Let's make the programmer a designer's job, and hire some designers to do the nurses job, then let the nurses work as lawyers to solve the problem is coming to the firm.

Comment: Hello Jonas and welcome to GDSE! It's not clear to me what your question is other than "Anything I should be aware of concerning red and green colors?" which is much too broad. I see you would like suggestions... Can you provide us with more details about what you would like suggestions for?

Comment: Hello. I think I'll just have to tell them to get a graphic designer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No offense meant, I **completely** understand the desire to keep clients happy and fulfill their requests regardless of how untenable they may be.

But just as one wouldn't ask a hospital orderly to diagnose a patient, even though they work in a tangent area to diagnosis..... well. They need to hire a designer. Graphic Design, like any profession, is not typically something someone can do well merely because a client wants them to. Just as there's a mountain of knowledge and experience which goes into building a web site, there's a mountain of knowledge and experience which goes into a well-crafted logotype. It's not simply "make a pretty picture" in most cases and almost *never* where a logotype is concerned.

As for red and green.. search for medical-themed logos... how many are red and green?

Red, sure.

And Green, sure..

but both? Almost never. There *might* be a reason for that.

I mean, it *could* be done. But typically blues are better suited to medical companies. Blues convey a subconscious feeling of "security" - think about it, hospitals, police, EMS, banks .... all blue in general. You can research more [here](https://www.empower-yourself-with-color-psychology.com/meaning-of-colors.html) or a Google search for "Meaning of Colors" will present more information. While a logo should be unique, it should also subtly convey the industry the company is in to some degree.

In general, when a client makes suggestions you aren't fond of, you talk them out of it by giving solid explanations as to *why* their suggestion may not work well. Without any experience, that can be difficult to do. Worse case is you present a couple ideas, one which tries to adhere to their suggestion and one you feel is much better suited for the need. Then try and talk them into the better options.

Answer (score 2):

> - I'm not a graphic designer
> - I don't like stars
> - I think green on red is a stupid choice
>
> This whole thing is giving me trouble and I'm out of ideas at what to come up with.

Of course! What did you expect? Started with such a negative predisposition of course you have neither arrived nor come to anything with this logo.

Let's try to reverse the problem, if it exists.

### I'm not a graphic designer

That's the biggest problem, but not yours. The problem is for the people who are asking you for your services as a designer knowing that you are not. You have not any tool to deal with, and the biggest problem will come after, a simple logo is just a starting point. But if they insist it's something you must deal with.

### I don't like stars

I wonder what kind of stars you don't like: four points stars, five points stars, six points stars, seven points stars, fifteen points stars, angled stars, rounded stars, long ray stars...? Big stars or small stars? Don't you think it's to extreme to say "I don't like stars"?

[image: montblanc]

Anyway, if a client says my logo must have a star, there are many graphic ways to make this star, has not to be a star shape over a typography.

[image: star]

We return to the previous point, you are not graphic designer, reason why you don't have the sufficient tools as to dominate the subject of a star added to a logo.

### I think green on red is a stupid choice

We, the graphic designers, tend to have a lot of respect for our work tools and the terminology we use. A color combination is never *stupid*, on the contrary, there are elements that we usually use as contrast and harmony, or adjacency and complementarity, or cold and warm combination, or saturation, tint and brightness. Well, data that a designer knows because work with them assiduously. I don't think in my case I am capable of saying that using a certain language to code is a stupid choice, since I am not a programmer.

**Absolutely all colors are part of our day to day, and there's no stupidity in them.** Who claims that a combination of colors is *stupid*, obviously is not a designer, and could never work with any color since he/she does not know them.

But, answering your question, there are many possibilities of using red and green in a medical image. In fact it is the basic combination in what refers to medical health: the fluid that gives us life and its complementary, normally used in medical uniforms for that reason. Maybe you are just imagining the color at its highest saturation, but both red and green have many variables in tone, saturation and brightness. Did you ask why they want red and green?

[image: Hospital logo]

*Hospital logo example from [pngimage.net](https://pngimage.net/logo-hospital-png-5/)*

---

RED, BLUE AND A STAR. This is the Madrid Health's logo base system: blue for sanity and red for the community flag, the star is a part of this flag:

[image: Madrid salud]

---

Finally, the designers usually like when the client give us the elements to use, as many of us, as part of our profession, we usually start from very structured bases to challenge and break them. But it's something that only a professional knows how to do.

Answer (score 0):

In medical circumstances green and red are not at all rare color combination. It can be a good selection when the target audience are medical professionals.

Personnel often wear green cloths to be able to see red things better. Thats a property of human sight. In addition: When someone watches intensively well lit red things, he can see green ghosts when he watches temporarily elsewhere. That's not so disturbing, if there's already something green - clothes, covers, room painting.

An example image:

[image]

You can see green clothed personnel, a red waste bin for biohazardous material and some flesh. Not at all unusual.

Other answers have told about stars. I have not much to add about it. But it must have some other meaning than where cartoonists draw stars (=sign of a need of some care). One possiblity is to give to it a principal role, as remarkable as the textual name:

[image]